# how to remove the element in json object when the value is null in a dataframe?

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I got a dataFrame like this:

```
   data
0  {"a": null, "b": 12, "c": null}
1  {"a": 15, "b": 12, "c": null}
2  {"a": 23, "b": 8, "c": null}
3  {"a": 5, "b":null, "c": null}
```

Is it possible to remove the element if the value is null?

The output would be like this:

```
   data
0  {"b": 12}
1  {"a": 15, "b": 12}
2  {"a": 23, "b": 8}
3  {"a": 5}
```

Comment: it didn't turn out a dataframe

Comment: the element still exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about :

```
data = """[
{"a": null, "b": 12, "c": null},
{"a": 15, "b": 12, "c": null},
{"a": 23, "b": 8, "c": null},
{"a": 5, "b":null, "c": null}
]"""
data = eval(data.replace("null", '"null"'))
fixed_rows = [{key: val for key, val in row.items() if val != "null"} for row in data]
```